# Best way to create a browser library with multiple files

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm working on a browser library (based on vanilla JS) and I need to load multiple JS files.

**Arbo**

```
/
  index.html
  lib/
    thelib.js
    thelib.css
    includes/
      thelib-part1.js
      thelib-part2.js
      thelib-part3.js
      ...
```

Making some research I found some solution :

### Multiple includes

I can easy resolve the issue by doing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/thelib.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/includes/thelib-part1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/includes/thelib-part2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/includes/thelib-part3.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/thelib.js"></script>
```

But it's annoying for the user..

### NodeJs tools

I ear about some tools, like **[Browserify](http://browserify.org/)** or **[RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html)** but can I use it without a server side rendering tools ?

### Async loading

I also can load manually from lib/the.js the other files, but I'm scared about problems who could append on different server configuration (ex, relative/absolute path ?, read file authorization?) 
And I worry about loading times (it will be longer to load each files one after the other right?)

I probably miss a solution, or not understanding well a listed solution ?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Yes; you should use a bundler like Browserify.

Comment: I understand the degree of opinion, but it's a generic problem without answer on stack (for my reseach, maybe miss something).
@SLaks, so I have to create a simple NodeJs server, add Browserify, bundle my lib and allow use to download the bundle ?

Comment: @Arthur: There are dozens of prebuilt development servers that do that for you.  See also Gulp, WebPack, and Mimosa.  In production, you should deploy the pre-compiled bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, I'm using now [WebPack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/) who can merge JS + others files into a js bundle and allow you to dev only a browser file (no running web server required)